# How can we get the previous state of the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my Application like below

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.somevalue" indeterminate " />
```

indeterminate is a directive which will change the state of the checkbox when the value of vm.somevalue is undefined.
Now when i am clicking on the checkbox from intermediate state, i need to unselect the the checkbox(vm.somevalue=false).

Any helps appreciated!

Comment: use `!` to get the opposite of current

Comment: @guradio that doesn't actually work, since `indeterminate` is not a state of the `checked` property. `indeterminate` is a property of its own, unrelated to `checked`. So if a checkbox is `indeterminate` that doesn't automatically mean that `checked` is true or false. It can be either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `click` event and store a value for the state in a data attribute.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]')
    .setCheckbox('unchecked') // set initial state
    .on('click', function(e) {
       var $checkbox = $(this);
       switch($checkbox.data('state')) {
         case 0: // unchecked
           $checkbox.setCheckbox('indeterminate');
           console.log('Previous state: unchecked | New state: indeterminate');
           break;
         case 1: // indeterminate
           $checkbox.setCheckbox('checked');
           console.log('Previous state: indeterminate | New state: checked');
           break;
         case 2: // checked
           $checkbox.setCheckbox('unchecked');
           console.log('Previous state: checked | New state: unchecked');
           break;
       }
    });
});

$.fn.setCheckbox = function(state) {
  return $(this).each(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    if (state=='unchecked') {
      $checkbox
        .data('state',0)
        .prop('indeterminate',false)
        .prop('checked',false);
    }
    else if (state=='indeterminate') {
      $checkbox
        .data('state',1)
        .prop('indeterminate',true)
        .removeProp('checked');
    }
    else if (state=='checked') {
      $checkbox
        .data('state',2)
        .prop('indeterminate',false)
        .prop('checked',true);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

In my example I toggle from `unchecked` to `indeterminate` to `checked`. I know you only asked for `indeterminate` to `unchecked`, but I wanted to give a complete answer that could be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the `click` event fires, the state of the checkbox has already been changed. You can get the original value is by listening for the `mouseup` event. This is only time we can know the current checked state of the checkbox AND that we can be sure the click event will be fired (the `mousedown` event also has the old value but the interaction can still be cancelled). From within the `mouseup` handler you then add a one time `click` event handler that sets the state:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
  if (event.which !== 1) return;
  
  if (checkbox.indeterminate) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
      checkbox.indeterminate = false;
      checkbox.checked = true;
    }, { once: true });
  } else if (!checkbox.checked) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
      checkbox.indeterminate = true;
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }, { once: true });
  }
  
}, { capture: true });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length, if it is zero then it is not checked.

```
var check=  $('input[type=checkbox]').length;
```

Use is() with :checked to get the result as boolean that is true if checkbox is checked.

```
var check=  $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
```